# What are some ways to make it harder for the client to manipulate the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, dom

I am going to be processing a lot of form data from the client using Ajax. Right now, my way of validating input is to add a 'validate' class to each form control that needs to be checked. When the user enters information (or submits the form) the script looks at the input of each control with that class and verifies its contents before moving to the next tab (or sending it to the server). The issue, of course, is that a user can easily remove the class and the item wouldn't be looked at.

While I will of course be validating the input on the server-side (*client data can never be trusted!*), a lot of the user-side content generation [new inputs, dynamic forms, removing/adding validate classes, etc.] depends on people not tinkering with the classes. While I know that the client can ultimately do whatever they want, what are some ways to make this process difficult for the client to manipulate?

So far I have thought about:

- Running a script at the beginning of the page load that grabs all the HTML inputs with the 'validate' class and stores them in a variable. When the user submits the data or moves to the next tab, instead of looking at the elements with the class 'validate', I instead look to validate the data compared to the contents of the variable.
- Adding data-validate HTML attributes to each input and doing the same thing as above (running a script and grabbing the inputs that need validation before the client has time to tinker with the settings)

Is there anything else that can be done? I am a little hesitant to use the above approaches because there may be new, dynamically generated form elements that need to be added/removed to the list; and this + grabbing the data at the beginning of the page load could cause a little unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I would say don't bother.  The only people who are going to do this are savvy enough to get around whatever you cook up; meanwhile, it will just make it harder for you or future devs to figure out WTF is going on

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking too. People can change ID's, classes, whatever basically. I just wanted to make it as hard as possible so that the average user (who may pick up on the idea of removing classes using any element inspector since it's super simple) would find it difficult to alter these things.

Comment: unless your average user are developers, they won't be trying.  it is definitely not super simple unless you normally do browser based dev.  even a lot of non-frontend devs don't know about browser dev tools.

Comment: If issue is very sensitive could have a server side GUID system that applies an identifier to all inputs and doesn't accept data that doesn't have a legitimate one when submitted. Would require ajax request for all new elements appended to DOM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"While I know that the client can ultimately do whatever they want..."

You just answered your question. If that's your starting point, why are you trying to make it *harder*? Is it worth my while to actually try to hack your site? If it is, I don't care that it's harder. Also, how hard can it be? Are you going to make it so hard to figure out the JavaScript that the next developer who looks at this code *also* won't be able to figure out what's going on?

Also, you're adding more code. Have you ever written code without bugs? I haven't. So, guaranteed, there are going to be bugs in this thing. So, in the off chance that 1 in a million users might try doing something bad, you'll end up stopping *lots* of legitimate users who get errors when they're using the site like they should.

Client side checking is ONLY meant to be nice to the end user, to give them immediate feedback. Period.

Might not be the answer you like, but it is the answer. :)

**Edit**: One last comment. Let's say you did make it REALLY hard. Would you then *not* do server side checking? Would you say to your boss, "Oh, we made it pretty hard to hack on the client side. They still *can*. We just made it hard. So no need to do server side checks." Of course not. So, if you're doing server side checks no matter what, you don't gain anything from trying to obfuscate on the client side.

Comment: Haha, that's what I figured! I knew it was a long shot, and there was some little part of me that was crossing my fingers hoping that there was SOME way more ingenious than my standard. Good to know we are all in the same boat on this one!